# Images in centered Masonry grid do not scale with browser resize

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, masonry

I'm using Masonry for displaying images in a grid view on my webpage. In order to center the grid container, I've followed the Masonry documentation and set the following:

```
isFitWidth: true
```

and

```
/* center container with CSS */
.grid {
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

This works perfectly. However, I'm finding that when isFitWidth is set to true, the images in the grid stay fixed at 380px (the actual size of the images), and they will not scale down below that size as the browser re-sizes. What can I do to have the grid container centered AND allow the images to scale down in size as the browser does?

As you can see below, I am using Bootstrap's img-responsive class for the images.

HTML:

```
<div id="container">
        <div class="grid">
            <div class="grid-item"><img class="img-responsive" src="images/small/8.jpg" alt="image"></div>
            <div class="grid-item"><img class="img-responsive" src="images/small/17.jpg" alt="image"></div>
            ...
```

CSS:

```
.grid-item {
  float: left;
  /*border: 1px solid #000;*/
  overflow:hidden;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.grid-item > * {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.grid {
  /* center */
  margin: 50px auto;
}

/* clear fix */
.grid:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define **width** for **.grid** class.

```
.grid{margin:0px auto; width:90% }
```

In case you do not get it. View this [working example](http://www.coderomeos.org/).